# Reference resources in kotlin kdoc are not clickable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, javadoc, kdoc

I want to mention a layout in my Javadoc which converted from java to Kotlin. In java it was:

```
/**
* ... inside the {@link R.layout#view_main}
*/
```

which was clickable, but when I converted this class using android studio tools. It is changed to:

```
/**
* ... inside the [R.layout.view_main]
*/
```

which is not clickable. How can I make it clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to import the R class into the class for which we are writing documentation. Otherwise, it will not be clickable.
It was solved in this way:

```
import my.app.R
/**
* text description [R.layout.activity_main]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin source link in the document comment will add like this

```
/**
 * text description
 * @see R.layout.activity_main
 *
 */
```

or link with the description in the same line will be like this

```
/**
 * text description @see [R.layout.activity_main]
 */
```

--

```
/**
 * text description @see [android.util.AndroidException] and this @see [android.util.AttributeSet]
 */
```

Comment: Thank you. However, my problem was silly. I did not import R in the file.